# Waiting cursor when a control is refreshing

Tags: wpf, data-visualization

I've got a `LineSeries` and refreshing it takes some time. it is normal, I insert kind of a lot of data.

The thing I want to do is to set the mouse cursor as the hourglass when the `LineSeries` is refreshing and reset the cursor to the regular mode when the job's done.

To be clear, I'd like to to this when the control is refreshing **not** when I'm loading the data from the database.

The question is not *how to change the cursor* but **How do I know the control has been loaded and refreshed**.

**Edit:**

As soon as the `ObservableCollection` has been modified, the PieSeries is updated. This process, in my case, takes some time.

```
<dvc:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Tickets, Converter={c:ResolutionChartConverter}}"
               IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Item1}"
               DependentValueBinding="{Binding Item2}">
```

In the code:

```
var result = this.GetSomeData();
this.Tickets.AddRange(result); 
// At this point, the PieSeries is updated and I want to know when to display
// the hourglass and when to hide it when the control is loaded.
```

Keep in mind that no control manage the mouse cursor when it's redrawed.

Comment: Are you asking how to set alternate cursors for a window?  Using code-behind or MVVM?

Comment: Change the cursor is not the problem. I'd like to know how I can know that the control (the `LineSeries`) has loaded and refreshed

Comment: Ok, you have a good answer from Ahmed Abaza below, but still consider the title also.

Answer (score 0):

If i got what you mean .. this should be what the answer of what you are looking for ..

first when the event of the `LineSeries` fired and before any thing change the cursor

and before the event ends change it back

Comment: It's not what I want. The mouse cursor is not modified when the control redraws. I have to do that manually and I want to know how I can know the control is updating.